# Add column to gridview from sql query (vb.net)

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview that stores data from a SQL query:

```
Dim sql2 As String
Dim ds2 As New DataSet

sql2 = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql2, con)
adapter.Fill(ds, sql2)

GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
GridView1.DataBind()
```

I had to add one more column to `MyTable` in the SQL database and now I would like to show that column in my gridview, and I don't know how to do it. Can someone help?

I've tried to find solutions on the web but none of them were using SQL as a source of new column in gridview.

Comment: `SELECT *, MyNewColumn FROM MyTable` where the new column would be calculated from other columns , maybe? or be empty? Please explain!

Comment: I will say, try using GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True or re-bind the Gridview in the developer environment.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes OP said he already added the column to his SQL table, so its is already in 'SELECT * ...' No?

Comment: If it's not showing already, you must have some other code manipulating the columns of the GridView. Additionally, **never use SELECT * in production code**.

Comment: Well, i assume that using 'SELECT * FROM MyTable' will always return every column form MyTable, including new column. New column won't be calculated from other columns neither will be empty.

Comment: @LukaszP you are correct in the assumption that `SELECT *` will return all columns. So if it is not showing in the GridView, there must be some other code affecting that GridView's columns.

Comment: @LukaszP You need to include the ASPX markup for the grid most likely. Getting the data is half the battle, however you need to add it to the grid in your aspx page.

Comment: @NickAbbot 's suggestion to use `AutoGenerateColumns = true` is one way to fix it but that runs the risk of other columns being added that were unintended and is generally bad practice, particularly considering your query is using `Select * ...`

Comment: If you are not using GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True in Gridview properties or before the DataBind(), then in the IDE you might have to change whatever DataSet is defining the layout and re-bind the GridView to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the aspx page and add your column to the grid you wish for it to show in. You can do so by adding whatever column type is needed and setting the `DataField` property to the name of your SQL column or alias.

A typical string field is below for your reference.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridDemo" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <!--... existing columns in grid view...-->
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="YourHeaderText" DataField="YourColumnName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you all for input. It turned out that i had AutoGenerateColumns = False, changing that to True solved issue.

Comment: While `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` will likely solve the problem at hand, it is generally bad practice to do so, especially when using `select * ... ` from your database. There are other factors to consider of course, but being explicit is usually the more reliable approach and certainly the more predictable one.